# How to develop an android application for opinion poll with pie chart

Tags: android

I want to make an opinion poll with pie chart. The questions are like this:

*Who will win in the Delhi elections?* 
*- Bjp* 
*- App* 
*- cong* 
*- I can't say*

then a submit button will be here 
after submiting, a pie chart will become visible of all the parties

Answer (score 0):

There is an jar **achartengine.jar** which can be used for creation of pie charts.
Details of this library can be found in **http://achartengine.org/**